# `display: table-cell` div ignores `overflow: hidden`

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to restrict the width of the columns by defining a `width` attribute on the `div.dcolumn` DOM element. However, for some reason this doesn't seem to work with an overflowing cell. I would like the overflowing cell's content to be hidden (e.g. the `9px` column) and the layout to be preserved as per the specified width values. What are my options?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html style='height:100%'>
       <head>
          <style>
            .header {
              background-color: #eeeeee;
              padding: 0 0 0 0;
              border: 1px solid #cccccc;
              cursor: default;
              -webkit-touch-callout: none;
              -webkit-user-select: none;
              -khtml-user-select: none;
              -moz-user-select: none;
              -ms-user-select: none;
              -o-user-select: none;
              user-select: none;
              overflow: hidden;
            }
    
            .dtable {
              display: table;
              position: relative;
              table-layout: fixed;
            }
            .drow {
              display: table-row;
            }
            .dcell {
              display: table-cell;
              overflow: hidden;
              padding: 0 0 0 0;
              border: 1px solid #cccccc;
              cursor: default;
            }
            .dcolumn {
              display: table-column;
            }
          </style>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div class="dtable" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 125px;">
             <div class="dcolumn" style="width: 39px;"></div>
             <div class="dcolumn" style="width: 19px;"></div>
             <div class="dcolumn" style="width: 9px;"></div>
             <div class="dcolumn" style="width: 39px;"></div>
             <div class="dcolumn" style="width: 19px;"></div>
             <div class="drow header" style="height: 25px;">
                <div class="dcell">0</div>
                <div class="dcell">1</div>
                <div class="dcell">2</div>
                <div class="dcell">3</div>
                <div class="dcell">4</div>
             </div>
             <div class="drow" style="height: 25px;">
                <div class="dcell">0:0</div>
                <div class="dcell">0:1</div>
                <div class="dcell">long line not truncated</div>
                <div class="dcell">0:3</div>
                <div class="dcell">0:4</div>
             </div>
             <div class="drow" style="height: 25px;">
                <div class="dcell">1:0</div>
                <div class="dcell">1:1</div>
                <div class="dcell">1:2</div>
                <div class="dcell">1:3</div>
                <div class="dcell">1:4</div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You should must mention ".dtable" width like ".dtable {width: 300px or else}" then ".dcell" should contain two CSS properties like: "white-space: nowrap;         text-overflow: ellipsis;".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: The trick is to set the total width of the table to the sum of all columns (and prevent wrapping with `white-space: nowrap`).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html style='height:100%'>
       <head>
          <style>
            .header {
              background-color: #eeeeee;
              padding: 0 0 0 0;
              border: 1px solid #cccccc;
              cursor: default;
              -webkit-touch-callout: none;
              -webkit-user-select: none;
              -khtml-user-select: none;
              -moz-user-select: none;
              -ms-user-select: none;
              -o-user-select: none;
              user-select: none;
              overflow: hidden;
            }
    
            .dtable {
              display: table;
              position: relative;
              table-layout: fixed;
            }
            .drow {
              display: table-row;
            }
            .dcell {
              display: table-cell;
              overflow: hidden;
              padding: 0 0 0 0;
              border: 1px solid #cccccc;
              cursor: default;
              white-space: nowrap;
            }
            .dcolumn {
              display: table-column;
            }
          </style>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div class="dtable" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 125px; width: 130px">
             <div class="dcolumn" style="width: 39px;"></div>
             <div class="dcolumn" style="width: 19px;"></div>
             <div class="dcolumn" style="width: 9px;"></div>
             <div class="dcolumn" style="width: 39px;"></div>
             <div class="dcolumn" style="width: 19px;"></div>
             <div class="drow header" style="height: 25px;">
                <div class="dcell">0</div>
                <div class="dcell">1</div>
                <div class="dcell">2</div>
                <div class="dcell">3</div>
                <div class="dcell">4</div>
             </div>
             <div class="drow" style="height: 25px;">
                <div class="dcell">0:0</div>
                <div class="dcell">0:1</div>
                <div class="dcell">long line not truncated</div>
                <div class="dcell">0:3</div>
                <div class="dcell">0:4</div>
             </div>
             <div class="drow" style="height: 25px;">
                <div class="dcell">1:0</div>
                <div class="dcell">1:1</div>
                <div class="dcell">1:2</div>
                <div class="dcell">1:3</div>
                <div class="dcell">1:4</div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

here I have added a `<span>` inside of `.dcell` for getting the ellipsis effect, as it won't work directly on `.dcell`. Also added the width to `.dcell` in this case `25px`.

this should work for you.

```css
.header {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dtable {
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.drow {
  display: table-row;
}

.dcell {
  display: table-cell;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 25px;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  cursor: default;
}

.dcolumn {
  display: table-column;
}

.cell-data {
  display:block;
  width:inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="dtable" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 125px;">
  <div class="dcolumn" style="width: 39px;"></div>
  <div class="dcolumn" style="width: 19px;"></div>
  <div class="dcolumn" style="width: 9px;"></div>
  <div class="dcolumn" style="width: 39px;"></div>
  <div class="dcolumn" style="width: 19px;"></div>
  <div class="drow header" style="height: 25px;">
    <div class="dcell">0</div>
    <div class="dcell">1</div>
    <div class="dcell">2</div>
    <div class="dcell">3</div>
    <div class="dcell">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="drow" style="height: 25px;">
    <div class="dcell">0:0</div>
    <div class="dcell">0:1</div>
    <div class="dcell">
      <span class="cell-data">long line not truncated</span></div>
    <div class="dcell">0:3</div>
    <div class="dcell">0:4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="drow" style="height: 25px;">
    <div class="dcell">1:0</div>
    <div class="dcell">1:1</div>
    <div class="dcell">1:2</div>
    <div class="dcell">1:3</div>
    <div class="dcell">1:4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "...as it won't work directly on .dcell" - that's because the `div.dcolumn` overwrites the directly assigned width. I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to change all columns at once (by changing `div.dcolumn`'s width somehow) without changing the width at each cell separately, so your suggestion won't work for me. Thanks anyway.